# Why is Riyadh (Saudi Arabia) Airport immigration staff so ill-mannered?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airport-transfer, saudi-arabia, riyadh

I was reading [this article](https://saudigazette.com.sa/article/61622) published in Saudi Gazette, and it came true to my case after 10 years.

[Saudi transit regulation](https://www.my.gov.sa/wps/portal/snp/servicesDirectory/servicedetails/8474/!ut/p/z0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjo8zivQIsTAwdDQz9LQwNzQwCnS0tXPwMvYwN3A30g1Pz9L30o_ArAppiVOTr7JuuH1WQWJKhm5mXlq8fYWFibqJfkO0eDgDtRK6y/).

I am an Indian and I am a Ph.D. student in mathematics, I had 1 month Italy Schengen Visa (28th April to 16th May, 2023). I was about to give a research speech in Rome. I arrived at Riyadh Airport (King Khalid Airport) on May 1, 2023, through "Air India" airline. I was supposed to transit from Riyadh Airport to Rome through "Wizz Air" airline.

When I arrived at Riyadh airport on late May 1, they said:

> Why didn't you use your Italy visa in the last 3 days (i.e., 28 April, 29 April, 30 April)?

I was surprised by the question. I told them I am coming from India and going to Italy, and once I will enter Italy will use my Italy Visa. But those people in the Visa+plus immigration section understand little English. They use little English and more Arabic.  The following happened one by one-

- their behavior is very rude, don't know the manner
- they asked me to book for deport flight and I said them I am booking my flight.
- they took my passport and coming boarding pass
- I finally booked my flight ticket (for deportation) at my own cost and told them I booked my ticket. They didn't respond much and said to sit down.
- then happened very bad thing. one immigration officer came to pick up an (unknown) bag where I was sitting outside the immigration office. He was telling in Arabic and I couldn't understand anything but his fingers were gesturing toward the bag and his language was very rough, he was literally forcing me to pick up the bag. After hesitation, I picked up the bag and followed him, he took me to a gate and opened the room and then very ill-manner way gestured me to enter the room with an (unknown) bag and then locked me in that room (no window, no food, no water, only one dirty washroom, of course, AC was there).
  -After entering the room, I saw other 8 passengers sitting/lying down there. And I discovered that I picked up that bag one of them already in the room. I was very irritated with how these immigration people are treating passengers, they are forced to carry others' bags. It is very illegal behavior.
- this was my 1st experience in my 31 years life span. My heart was nervous because it was a closed room with no window (worse than prison). You can not call them from that room. Only you can knock on the door from inside. After 1 hour someone came to take another 1 person for boarding. I said I booked my flight and boarding will start in 3 hours, let me sit outside. They said roughly that we will come when your boarding time will start. They didn't supply food or water.
- finally, one officer came and took me to the immigration office and one officer took me to the boarding gate I boarded a return flight via Abu Dhabi Airport (UAE).

This is the story. It was a horrible experience, they were treating us like criminals for irrelevant reasons. To my opinion, they are very ill-mannered, not professional. These immigration officers need proper training and English-speaking skills to communicate with international passengers. Their administration should look into it.

At the cost, I missed my research conference in Rome.
My question-

> Why they locked passengers with (similar situations) into the closed room? After all, it is the airport, full of security, where we can go out? I had an experience with the Dubai Airport (UAE) immigration office, and they treated me (and all others) very well, provided food, and solved my issue in 2022. In that respect, Riyadh Airport staff has a very lack of professionalism and training.

> How can I share my feedback regarding the immigration staff of Riyadh Airport with their airport authority? If so, what is the right place or email of that authority?

Of course, I can write reviews in several travel forums. I have already sent 3 emails to the Indian embassy in Saudi, the Saudi embassy in India, and the Riyadh Airport feedback section.

Where to write the review that might help others?

Comment: I'm sorry this happened to you, but unfortunately this kind of thing happens to Indians in Saudi Arabia all the time.

Comment: Did you have a visa for Saudi Arabia? Did you have checked bags?

Comment: @Doc, I didn't have a Saudi visa because their website mentions transit visa is not required for less than 12 hours of layover. I also emailed them before travel and confirmed it. I didn't have a checked-in bag and so I didn't have to pass through immigration. I was simply sitting for an international connecting flight. After two hours, someone took me to the immigration office and all this happened.  Suppose even if a Saudi visa were required for transit, then also they should behave officially. Why did they treat me (or others) badly?

Comment: @Doc, [Saudi transit regulation](https://www.my.gov.sa/wps/portal/snp/servicesDirectory/servicedetails/8474/!ut/p/z0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjo8zivQIsTAwdDQz9LQwNzQwCnS0tXPwMvYwN3A30g1Pz9L30o_ArAppiVOTr7JuuH1WQWJKhm5mXlq8fYWFibqJfkO0eDgDtRK6y/)

Comment: Did you already have your Wizz Air boarding card? A visa does not *guarantee* entry to Schengen or anywhere else, come to that. In your case, perhaps they considered your flight itinerary and transit in SA unusual and that an *unused* Schengen visa wasn’t sufficiently convincing

Comment: @Traveller, I downloaded the Wizz boarding card after online check-in. At first, how can I use a Schengen visa before entering to Schengen area? Second, their (Saudi) own rule might be something like that, and acted it and booked my return flight. My main question- Why would they behave ill-mannered way? Why would they lock in a room? I came to UAE from Saudi and they said I can travel to Italy, it doesn't matter when my Schengen visa became active, but as long as I have an active period, I can travel to the Schengen area.  Still, my main question-why would they behave ill-mannered way ?

Comment: @MAS Their country, their (interpretation of) their rules I guess. Any interaction with immigration officials can seem abrupt, even when all goes well. Detaining deportees under lock & key is very probably normal worldwide, while what you consider to be rude may not be seen as ill-mannered in a different country/culture.

Comment: @Traveller, [read this](https://saudigazette.com.sa/article/61622). I have experience in Dubai last year when I was supposed to travel to Hungary from Dubai but according to the flight i would arrive at Hungary 30 minutes before my visa being active. The immigration office treated me very well and said to wait 1 night and go next day. They provided free foods, even the airline (flydubai) issued free ticket for Hungary since I missed the previous ticket. It was my own mistake but the airport fully helped me, once they understood i will attend a research conference. I don't know glock culture t

Comment: @Traveller, one can not justify the rude behaviour. It is not normal. Because one officer forced me to carry an unknown bag, which belongs to other person. Does this seem normal to you ? Isn't like slavery? They can request but how can they force?